# How to Organize Angular 2 Files on Webhost that Uses Public Folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have currently updated my server from Shared VPS to dedicated server so I can start using an Node.js environment along with gaining root access to my own server.

Everything is fine, I have git cloned the angular/quickstart.git project for practice.

My web service requires that I use a public folder for my domain, which is fine, but simply downloading all files to my root directory looks like this:

```
site.com/public (pre-existing folder on server)
site.com/app
site.com/package.json
site.com/index.html
site.com/systemjs.config.js
site.com/tsconfig.json
```

Among other files.

I am able to "npm start" the project, but I cannot see any files, because they are all root access and aren't in the "public" folder.

If I download the files to the public folder instead, it looks like this:

```
site.com/public/app
site.com/public/package.json
site.com/public/index.html
site.com/public/systemjs.config.js
site.com/public/tsconfig.json
```

With all of these files remaining exposed.

What exactly should I do at this point?

I know how to install express and set certain folders to mimic the "public" folder, but wouldn't that require me running the internal "app/app.js" file from Angular 2 as well as the "app.js" file from a root Express.js installation.

This seemingly should be a lot easier than it is, but my first time practicing on a production server, as opposed to my desktop for Angular 2.

Any suggestions, design practices or form factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is the [angular/quickstart.git](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) project was created ONLY for very simple demos, that should not be used for a production server as you have, it's only for localhost server.

A good and popular solution will be to use [angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), this will generate all the files in a /dist folder, with that you can have your node express on that dedicated server and use the /dist as a /public

Also another story will be that you can have a [Continuous Integration](https://aws.amazon.com/devops/continuous-integration/) on a cloud server, like heroku or azure, etc... but I think this is already too much.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as it was a little more descriptive and therefore more helpful than the first response. Also for the optional 'continuous integration' cloud server solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are messing things up here. AngularJs is "Client side" and NodeJs is used for building the application. If you would like to have an Express server side, then this is something different.

If using angular CLI, then the Client is generated in the dist folder and only the files in there are then copied to the Public folder. The Express App would then run in a running NodeJs Server anywhere on the Server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At work we have separate servers, but locally on my computer, I've always combined the two, since these are more hobby based. But this is a good solution as well.